# Math.nextUp(arg) is always same as arg + Math.ulp(arg)?

Tags: java, floating-point

`Math.nextUp(arg)` is always same as `arg + Math.ulp(arg)` or am I missing something?

```
System.out.println( 0.5 + Math.ulp(0.5));         // 0.5000000000000001 
System.out.println( Math.nextUp(0.5));            // EXACTLY same
System.out.println( Math.nextAfter(0.5, 1000));   // EXACTLY same
```

But **-1, -2, -0.5 are the only exclusions (?)** from the "rule" above that were found so far. Besides, the difference is always only in the rightmost decimal digit printed:

```
    System.out.println(Math.nextUp(-0.5));     // -0.49999999999999994
    System.out.println(-0.5 + Math.ulp(-0.5)); // -0.4999999999999999

    System.out.println(Math.nextUp(-1.0));     // -0.9999999999999999
    System.out.println(-1.0 + Math.ulp(-1.0)); // -0.9999999999999998

    System.out.println(Math.nextUp(-2.0));     // -1.9999999999999998
    System.out.println(-2.0 + Math.ulp(-2.0)); // -1.9999999999999996
```

> ***public static double ulp(double d)***
>
> Returns the size of an ulp of the argument. An ulp, unit in the last
>   place, of a double value is the *positive distance between this
>   floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude*.
>
> [ulp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) of a specific real number value is the *distance between the two
>   floating-point values* **bracketing that numerical value**.
>
> ***public static double nextUp(double d)***
>
> Returns the *floating-point value
>   adjacent to d in the direction of positive infinity.*

According to API, `Math.nextUp(arg)` and `arg + Math.ulp(arg)` should be equivalent for any arg (besides maybe some special values like NaN, Infinity, MAX_VALUE, MIN_VALUE)...

Comment: Generally powers of two are annoying when trying to express properties involving ULPs. I believe the property you ask about is true for all finite floating-point values that are not +/- a power of two.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider -1. The ULP of -1 is 2<sup>−52</sup>. Numbers in the interval (−2, −1] are spaced 2<sup>−52</sup> apart. However, numbers in the interval (−1, −½] are spaced 2<sup>−53</sup> apart. So the next number up from −1 is −1+2<sup>−53</sup>, not −1+2<sup>−52</sup>.